# C++17: compiler support for pmr namespace classes

Tags: c++, c++17, dynamic-memory-allocation

I want to experiment with `pmr::memory_resource` for dynamic memory pooling.

[This](https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx-status.html) page and [this](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support) page purport to list C++17 features and indicate compiler support for each. However, I do not find `pmr`, `memory_resource` or `polymorphic_allocator` listed here.

Also, what is the most recent proposal on these proposed features? I found [this](https://isocpp.org/blog/2014/02/n3916) revised proposal from early 2014. Is that the latest?

Comment: If it helps, I've got MIT-licensed sample implementations of most of `std::pmr` [in this repo](https://github.com/Quuxplusone/from-scratch/blob/master/include/scratch/memory_resource). You could always copy them into your project for experimental purposes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Polymorphic allocator belonging to the `pmr` namespace are not compiler features; they're new **standard library features**. You should refer to these pages:

- ["libstdc++ C++1z status"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/status.html#status.iso.201z)
- ["libc++ C++1z status"](http://libcxx.llvm.org/cxx1z_status.html)

Note that polymorphic memory resources and polymorphic allocators are part of the [**"Library Fundamentals V1 TS Components for C++17"**](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0220r1.html).

- libstdc++ supports it as part of GCC 9.1
- libc++ support is marked as "in progress"

  [image]

Comment: gcc is confusing, since the image you took under C++14 says "Partial", where as the "Library Fundamentals V1 TS Components: memory_resource" line under C++1z simply says "No."

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: whoops. Fixed!

Comment: So the answer is "no" for gcc, and I would need to use clang. Do you happen to know this from experience?

Comment: Just to be sure, it's me that doesn't know how to read these tables or I've to use the latest versions to be able to use a pmr allocator?